# Mobile menu will only toggle on

Tags: javascript

I've got a mobile menu that will toggle on, but it just won't go away.

my JS:

```
const menu = document.getElementById("mobile-menu");
const button = document.getElementById("navButton");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (menu.style.display="none") {
        menu.style.display="block"
    } else {
        menu.style.display="none"
    }
})
```

and my PHP in header.php:

```
 wp_nav_menu(array(
        'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
        'menu_id' => 'mobile-menu',
```

What am I missing to make this toggle off?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is no WordPress-specific question and must be considered off-topic.

Comment: I believe that it is something to do with how WordPress generates menus or how JS integrates with templates, because it's a fairly simple JS script that isn't doing what it should. Even JS lifted directly from a tutorial like W3 schools will not work in this case. I've still not cracked it!

Answer (score 0):

Please read this documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

`menu_id`
(string) The ID that is applied to the ul element which forms the menu. The default is the menu slug, incremented.

`container_id`
(string) The ID that is applied to the container.

Try to add `container_id` in `wp_nav_menu` array(), I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
  'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
  'menu_id' => 'mobile-menu',
  'container_id'    => 'mobile-menu',
  )
)
```

Comment: I've tried adding `container_id`, with and without `menu_id` and the problem persists apparently unchanged. The only difference is there is another div around the menu. Why should container_id work?
I've also tried adding and removing a class, but while the function runs on each click (for instance a console log will run) the CSS doesn't change after the first time

Comment: Try to move your JS from header to footer, this might help you out. Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid it's already in the footer!